# Convert data file to blob

Tags: javascript, html

How to get a blob?

HTML:

```
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
```

JavaScript:

```
function previewFile() {
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  // Get blob?
  console.log(file);
}
```

Comment: `file instanceof Blob; // true`

Answer (score 118, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, `file` is a `blob`:

```
file instanceof Blob; // true
```

And you can get its content with the file reader API https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

function readFile(event) {
  textarea.textContent = event.target.result;
  console.log(event.target.result);
}

function changeFile() {
  var file = input.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', readFile);
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

input.addEventListener('change', changeFile);
```

```html
<input type="file">
<textarea rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto , @Daniel : if I want to send the blob over websocket, What object is required to be sent from abv code ?  shall I send `ws.send(reader)` ???

Answer (score 23):

A file object is an instance of Blob but a blob object is not an instance of File

```
new File([], 'foo.txt').constructor.name === 'File' //true
new File([], 'foo.txt') instanceof File // true
new File([], 'foo.txt') instanceof Blob // true

new Blob([]).constructor.name === 'Blob' //true
new Blob([]) instanceof Blob //true
new Blob([]) instanceof File // false

new File([], 'foo.txt').constructor.name === new Blob([]).constructor.name //false
```

If you must convert a file object to a blob object, you can create a new Blob object using the array buffer of the file. See the example below.

```
const file = new File(['hello', ' ', 'world'], 'hello_world.txt', {type: 'text/plain'});
//or const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(e.target.result)], {type: file.type });
    console.log(blob);
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

As pointed out by @bgh you can also use the arrayBuffer method of the File object. See the example below.

```
const file = new File(['hello', ' ', 'world'], 'hello_world.txt', {type: 'text/plain'});
//or const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

file.arrayBuffer().then((arrayBuffer) => {
    const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)], {type: file.type });
    console.log(blob);
});
```

If your environment supports async/await you can use a one-liner like below

```
const fileToBlob = async (file) => new Blob([new Uint8Array(await file.arrayBuffer())], {type: file.type });
console.log(await fileToBlob(new File(['hello', ' ', 'world'], 'hello_world.txt', {type: 'text/plain'})));
```

Comment: These days it's probably a better idea to use use the `arrayBuffer()` method instead (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer). 
Something like:

`let blob = new Blob(await file.arrayBuffer());`

Answer (score -1):

```
async function FileToString (file) {
    try {
        let res = await file.raw.text();
        console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```